# Динамическое добавление кода HTML и обработка его Jinja

Tags: javascript, html, django, jinja2

Мне необходимо на HTML странице пользователя отображать таблицу из двух столбцов с возможностью динамического добавления строк. В поле столбца один я вывожу список объектов передаваемого класса, во втором столбце пользователь вводит информацию (Создаю таблицу ингредиентов и ввожу их кол-во для приготовления блюда).

Реализовал метод на js, который добавляет строку.

```
function AddItem() {
    item++;
    $('#ItemInRecipTable').find('tbody').append('<tr><td><select name="item-choice" 
          class="form-control">{% for item in items %}<option value={{ item.id }}>{{ 
          item.name }}</option>{% endfor %}</select></td><td><input type="number" 
          name="amount-item" class="form-control"></td></tr>');
}
```

И вот тут столкнулся с проблемой... В этом коде есть часть, которая должна быть обработана Jinja

```
 {% for item in items %}
     <option value={{ item.id }}>{{item.name }}</option>
 {% endfor %}
```

Но на деле я получаю просто {{item.name }}, потому что Jinja не обрабатывает новый код.

Вопрос... Как динамически добавлять html код разметки таблицы таким образом, чтобы Jinja его подхватывала?

Думал это сделать через {% include "add_item.html" %}, но тогда нужна какая логика обработки флага, которую я себе не представляю.

Прошу подсказать и направить на путь истинный.

Comment: jinja работает на стороне сервера. Код html который вы просто добавляете на фронтенде jinja никак обработать не может. Нужно или на сервере в django эту логику выполнять, либо получать с сервера просто голые данные (json), и формировать html средствами js.

Comment: @insolor, понял, спасибо. С json еще дела не имел... Не подскажите что читать, смотреть, копать, чтобы разобраться как его передать на фронт и там с ним работать?

Comment: Ну, у вас должен быть REST сервис, который данные будет отдавать. На Django реализуется через Django REST Framework (DRF) либо через Django Ninja (например). DRF сильно более популярный. Со стороны фронтенда обычно используются свои фреймворки, тут я уже не подскажу.

Comment: @insolor почитал про JsonResponse... Если я правильно понял он просто передаст словарь в виде json, но не HTML шаблон, как в случае с render? Есть ли какие-то способы передать шаблонную страницу с к ней прикрепить json? Я не до конца понимаю как правильно трактовать Ваши слова "и формировать html средствами js"

Comment: "и формировать html средствами js" - js код на основе полученных с сервера данных модифицирует DOM. С сервера просто приходит просто список данных для строк таблицы. Шаблон нужен только для первоначального наполнения страницы.

Comment: Посмотрите тут примеры, что-то в этом роде: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: "Шаблон нужен только для первоначального наполнения страницы" - либо шаблонизатор вообще может не использоваться, загружаться просто подгружаться html как статика, в нем выполняться js, который уже формирует страницу.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я тему "раскурил" и понял, про REST и js... Сейчас буду упражняться. Если моя идея правильная, то я добавлю ответ.